# NSMutableArray to NSDictionary iOS 3.1.3 problem

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have a problem when I try to run my app on an iOS 3.1.3
I run my app in 4.1 and theres is no problem, but with 3.1.3 my app crash.
My app crash in this line:

```
NSDictionary *atm= (NSDictionary *)[atmData objectAtIndex:0];
```

And here is a piece of my code:

```
DataHelper *mydata = [[DataHelper alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *atmData = [mydata getAllAtmByLocation:appDelegate.userLocation];    
if(atmData != nil){
   NSDictionary *atm= (NSDictionary *)[atmData objectAtIndex:0];
   //...
}
```

Like I said this issue happens only on iOS 3.1.3, in 4.1 it works perfectly.
Thx for ur help!!

Comment: I can't see it cuz dun know why but xCode doesn't let me debug the app, it install it en my iPhone and then i run it, but cant debug it.

Comment: Please post error details such as console output. It could be that your data is just nil on that version because some API you call is not supported in 3.1.3. You are accessing the array without checking to  see if it has elements so that will cause a crash if it is empty.

Comment: What does it output to the console when it crashes? You should check that your array is not empty before trying to get an element from it.

Comment: @Felipe: If you're using Xcode 3.x, check organizer, your device, console.

Comment: The contents of the console can also be seen in the Xcode Organizer. Try Run -> Debug from the menu to debug your app from Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you're getting a subscript out of range error. Is it possible that `getAllAtmByLocation:`is returning an empty array? You might change your conditional to:

```
if (atmData != nil && [atmData count] > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes!! Thx dde that solve my problem. But why this happens only in 3.1.3?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `[atmData count]` and make sure the array actually contains an element.  Maybe whatever you're using to populate the array isn't supported in 3.1.3.